# object.find fails in rakefile even though I'm including environment

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I've got a rakefile with a cron job in it that accesses one of my models and then does a search on my database.  I'm including my environment and see to be able to create my object, but when I try to run the "find" method, I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `find' for #<Feeder:0x103611df0>
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.0.4/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:364:in `method_missing'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:46:in `method_missing'
/Users/josh.kerr/Documents/Projects/joshkerr.jekyll/Rakefile:28
/Users/josh.kerr/Documents/Projects/joshkerr.jekyll/Rakefile:20:in `each'
/Users/josh.kerr/Documents/Projects/joshkerr.jekyll/Rakefile:20
/Users/josh.kerr/Documents/Projects/joshkerr.jekyll/Rakefile:18:in `each'
/Users/josh.kerr/Documents/Projects/joshkerr.jekyll/Rakefile:18
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

Here is the code:

```
require 'rails/all'
require 'rake/clean'
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
require 'rubygems'
require 'sqlite3'

desc "This task is called by the Heroku cron add-on"
task :cron => :environment do
  puts "Running cron at #{Time.now.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')}..."
  require 'app/models/feeder'
  num_feeds = 10
  feedurls = ["http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/2205491.rss","http://github.com/joshkerr.atom","http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/joshkerr/uploads","http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=95219360@N00&lang=en-us&format=rss_200","http://www.google.com/reader/public/atom/user%2F00755727578217480286%2Fstate%2Fcom.google%2Fbroadcast"]

  feedurls.each do |feed|
    rawfeed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(feed)
    for i in 0..num_feeds do    
        # Database call
        fed = Feeder.new
        fed.title = rawfeed.entries[i].title
        fed.published = rawfeed.entries[i].published
        fed.url = rawfeed.entries[i].url
        fed.feed_id = rawfeed.entries[i].entry_id        

        fed.find(1) # <- FAILS HERE!!!
        #if not fed.Find(1) then

          if fed.url.include? "twitter.com" then        
                  fed.feed_service="twitter"
          elsif fed.url.include? "github.com" then
                  fed.feed_service="github"
          elsif fed.url.include? "flickr.com" then
                  fed.feed_service="flickr"
          elsif fed.url.include? "youtube.com" then
                  fed.feed_service="youtube"
          elsif fed.feed_id.include? "google.com" then
                  fed.feed_service="reader" 
          else
              fed.feed_service = "reader"
          end

          fed.save    
        #end
    end
  end

  puts "Done creating feed"

  puts "done."

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` is a method on an `ActiveRecord` class, and is not defined on an instance of an `ActiveRecord` object. So, to find the `Feeder` with ID of 1, you'd call `Feeder.find(1)`.

The other thing I noticed is this: the line `task :cron => :environment` means that the environment is already being loaded--this includes `rails/all`, `rubygems` (you're using Rails 3, which uses Bundler), `sqlite3` (assuming it's in your `Gemfile` and you've run `bundle install` to generate your `Gemfile.lock`, and all your models. Try removing all the `requires` lines and see if your rake task still executes.